# File is not being send or recieved from asynch XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest, apache-commons-fileupload

I need to send the image to the server, i am using angular 2 so the reqest have to be asynch. This is the code i use to send the image on the client:

```
return Observable_1.Observable.create(function (observer) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            formData.append('image', image);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next({ response: xhr.response, status: xhr.status });
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                    else {
                        observer.error({ response: xhr.response, status: xhr.status });
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            if (headers)
                for (var _i = 0, headers_1 = headers; _i < headers_1.length; _i++) {
                    var header = headers_1[_i];
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(header.header, header.value);
                }
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
```

The code i use to hande the requst on server

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/product/image", consumes = {"multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data"})
    public ResponseEntity<ImageToken> postImage(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {
        MultipartFile file = request.getFile(request.getFileNames().next());
        return imageService.saveImage("/products/", file);
    }
```

I realy have no idea what is wrong. The handler is being trigered but throws exception on request.getFileName(), and i don`t see any files inside of the request in debugger.

Here is my multipart resolver conf:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver =  new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
        resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(50000000);
        return resolver;
    }
```

My versions of apache commons and spring boot:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let Spring do the multipart retrieval by specifying a multipart file parameter and annotating it with the part's name:

```
public ResponseEntity<ImageToken> postImage(@RequestPart("image") final MultipartFile file) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I know and have tried it before, but it does not change the fact that the request itself does not bare any files, although i can see them being send, in developer tools =(